# xgboost learning rate scheduler callback

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network, xgboost, image-classification

i'm using xgboost for image classification and whenever i want to use a LearningRateScheduler or LearningRateDecay callbacks i got some errores. i use the same functions that i use for LearningRateScheduler in keras.

```
def read_lr_from_file(lr_file,epoch):
with open ('LR.txt' , mode='r') as lr_file:
    for line in lr_file:
        step,lr = line.split(':')
        lr = lr.strip()
        if int(step) <= epoch and float(lr) > 0:
            learning_rate = float(lr)
    return learning_rate


def get_scheduler(lr_file):
def scheduler(epoch):
    lr = read_lr_from_file(lr_file, epoch)
    return lr
return scheduler

learning_rate = xgboost.callback.LearningRateScheduler(get_scheduler('LR.txt'))

trained_model = xgboost.train(params= params_1, dtrain= train_dataset , evals=[(val_dataset, 'eval')],num_boost_round = 1000,early_stopping_rounds=50,callbacks=[learning_rate],verbose_eval= False)
```

and it goes printing the message below on and on:

"[20:33:17] WARNING: C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.5.1/src/learner.cc:576:
Parameters: { "min_chiled_weight", "n_estimators", "rate_drop" } might not be used.

This could be a false alarm, with some parameters getting used by language bindings but
then being mistakenly passed down to XGBoost core, or some parameter actually being used
but getting flagged wrongly here. Please open an issue if you find any such cases.

[20:33:20] WARNING: C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.5.1/src/learner.cc:1115: Starting in XGBoost 1.3.0, the default evaluation metric used with the objective 'multi:softmax' was changed from 'merror' to 'mlogloss'. Explicitly set eval_metric if you'd like to restore the old behavior.
[20:33:20] WARNING: C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.5.1/src/learner.cc:576:
Parameters: { "min_chiled_weight", "n_estimators", "rate_drop" } might not be used.

This could be a false alarm, with some parameters getting used by language bindings but
then being mistakenly passed down to XGBoost core, or some parameter actually being used
but getting flagged wrongly here. Please open an issue if you find any such cases."

i would be grateful if you can help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a reasonable callable object about callbacks, see the demo below:

```
def lr_decay(epoch):
    lr = init_lr*0.999**epoch   # *0.99 0.9 0.995 0.999
    print(epoch,':',lr,)
    return lr
callbacks = xgb.callback.LearningRateScheduler(reduce_lr)
bst = XGBClassifier()
eval_set = [(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)]
bst.fit(x_train,y_train,eval_set=eval_set,callbacks=[callbacks])
```